# SimpleXML doesn't show the value

Tags: php, xml, soap, simplexml

I am wondering why the below code doesn't show the value of processResponse tag while it shows the whole XML and the Body tag.

This is the XML which I am handling

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<env:Header>
<wsa:MessageID>urn:df1231asfer5e4564affds</wsa:MessageID>
<wsa:ReplyTo><wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:Address></wsa:ReplyTo>
</env:Header>
<env:Body>
<processResponse xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/EligibilityProcess/EligibilityProcess/EligibilityBPEL">
   <generatedMessageRefNo>451</generatedMessageRefNo>
   <providerRefNo>41</providerRefNo>
   <tpaRequestId>4184612387</tpaRequestId>
   <contractHolder>Rami Zbeeb</contractHolder>
   <contractNo>81456954</contractNo>
   <guarantorName>ANC</guarantorName>
   <eligibilityStatus>Success</eligibilityStatus>
   <eligibilityReason xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
   <messageOrNotes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
   <patientShare></patientShare>
   <consentForm></consentForm>
   <webServTechStatus>Success</webServTechStatus>
   <replyCode xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
   <replyDescription xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
</processResponse></env:Body></env:Envelope>';
```

I am using the SimpleXML class:

```
$res = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
```

When I am showing the body XML it works:

```
$str = $res->children('env',true)->Body->asXML();
echo "<pre>",htmlentities($str),"</pre>";
```

However when showing the processResponse XML or string it doesn't work:

```
$str = $res->children('env',true)->Body->processResponse->asXML();
echo "<pre>",htmlentities($str),"</pre>";
```

Kindly advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the children of `Body` to get the `processResponse`:

```
$str = $res->children('env',true)->Body->children()->processResponse->asXML();
echo "<pre>",htmlentities($str),"</pre>";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but why I can't access it without using children method?

Comment: This is necessary because the `->children()` method "switches to" a particular namespace - so if you wanted something else in the `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/` namespace, you wouldn't need to call `->children()` a second time, but if you want to switch back to the default namespace (technically, switch to the `http://xmlns.oracle.com/EligibilityProcess/EligibilityProcess/EligibilityBPEL` namespace) you need to call `->children()` again to make the switch. This feels more natural when working with documents with a more even mix of namespaced nodes, rather than just a wrapper.